# Use Twofold which() condition but keep Indices from the beginning in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
eData<- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-2,0,2,0,-2,2,-2,2,0,0,-2,0,2,0,-2,0,0,2,-2,0,1,0,1
                  ,0,-2,2,-2,0,1,0,1,0,-2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,-2,2,-2,0,1,0,0,1,0,-2,0,2,0,-2,0,2,0,0
                  ,0,-2,0,2,-2,0,2,0,-2,1,1,0,-2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                  ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

In a next step i search for all `Indices` which have the value `-2` but I want the value next to it so my code is:

```
which(eData == -2) + 1
[1]  25 114 118 120 124 128 132 138 140 146 164 166 173 177 183 186 190 194 281 343 387 456
```

Looking at the actual data I want all `values > 0`:

```
eData[which(eData == -2) + 1]
[1] 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

So i do:

```
which( eData[which(eData == -2) + 1] > 0)
3  4  8 11 17
```

But the final result I really want is:

```
result
118 120 138 164 190
```

Meaning the corresponding Indices for the original data.
So that i can do:

```
eData[result]
2 2 2 2 1
```

like

```
eData[118] 
2
etc.
```

How can I archive something like this all I tried yielded just an error message or got me just the "wrong" result `3  4  8 11 17`:

```
which( eData[which(eData == -2) + 1] > 0)
```

But I want the **Original** values.
I have the impression that it cant be that difficult, but cant figure it out myself.

Comment: You can also put the functions that you wrote together. So no new coding is necessary `(which(eData == -2) + 1)[!!eData[which(eData == -2) + 1]]`

Answer (score 2):

From what you are saying, you are looking for strictly positive values which are after a value equal to -2. You can do an `intersect` in order to have the position of those numbers.

```
intersect(which(eData >0),which(eData == -2)+1)
# [1] 118 120 138 164 190
```

and you indeed have

```
eData[intersect(which(eData >0),which(eData == -2)+1)]
# [1] 2 2 2 2 1 # the values of eData(118), ... : all > 0

eData[intersect(which(eData >0),which(eData == -2)+1)-1]
# [1] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 # the values of eData(118-1), ... : all equal to -2
```

or you could also use

```
which(eData>0 & c(NA,eData[-length(eData)])==-2)
# [1] 118 120 138 164 190
```